# Compile C program for DES using OpenSSL

Tags: c

I got a problem during compiling my C program for DES encrytion/decryption using OpenSSL project on ubuntu.The compiling command is :

```
gcc -o des_cbc des_cbc.c -lcrypt
```

and I got the following errors:

In function main':

```
des_cbc.c:(.text+0x1fb): undefined reference to `DES_set_key_checked'
des_cbc.c:(.text+0x283): undefined reference to `DES_encrypt1'
des_cbc.c:(.text+0x2da): undefined reference to `DES_encrypt1'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably needing to add the `-lssl` flag... let me read the `nm` output of the libraries to see where those functions are...

**EDIT:**

Here is what I am seeing on my system, you shouldn't need the `-lssl` flag because, the symbols are showing up in the libcrypto library...

```
nm /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib | grep DES_set_key_checked
000000000008c9d0 T _DES_set_key_checked
```

and:

```
nm programing/src/openssl/libcrypto-1.0.0e.a | grep DES_set_key_checked
0000000000000340 T _DES_set_key_checked
0000000000000f00 S _DES_set_key_checked.eh
```

but it is possible that your version is missing these symbols because they were intentionally not compiled into the library.

Comment: Agree.  Looks like the `ssl` library was not linked.

Comment: @abelenky I don't thinks so... on my system the DES symbols look to be in the crypto lib, and not in the ssl lib

Comment: @GradyPlayer Thanks for your post!! I have made the changes and now I got the key generation error.Please visit this Link :           http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Generation-of-DES-key-for-use-in-DES-encrypt1-tp52999p53033.html                                                                                                                      Please respond ASAP!! Thanks Vineet

Comment: @abelenky I have linked the ssl library but now I got the key generation error. Please visit this Link : http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Generation-of-DES-key-for-use-in-DES-encrypt1-tp52999p53033.html   Please respond ASAP!! Thanks

Comment: @VineetPandey you should run it with a debugger and see where it segfaults or if you have a stack trace, add that to your question.

Comment: @GradyPlayer the biggest problem am facing in the key generation where it shows the output as "key error: -1 ".Please help over this and for segmentation error,I will check it with debugger.Thanks

Comment: @GradyPlayer After scanned from Valgrind :==28908== Invalid write of size 1 ==28908==    at 0x8048B4C: translate (in /home/vineet/ssl)
==28908==    by 0x8048865: main (in /home/vineet/ssl)
==28908==  Address 0x4026b34 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==28908== LEAK SUMMARY:
==28908==    definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==28908==      possibly lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==28908==    still reachable: 1,574 bytes in 24 blocks
==28908== ERROR SUMMARY: 14 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 25 from 8)
Segmentation fault

Comment: @GradyPlayer Please go through this link: http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Generation-of-DES-key-for-use-in-DES-encrypt1-td52999.html#a53033   -- getting the segmentation fault error.Please help me to resolve this issue ASAP!! Thanks

Comment: what line is it segfaulting on?

Comment: @GradyPlayer After line-81,I can't find its execution.Please go through this link: http://ideone.com/PgtWou  . Please respond ASAP!! Thanks

Comment: @abelenky After line-81,I can't find its execution.Please go through this link: ideone.com/PgtWou . Please respond ASAP!! Thanks

Comment: This question was asked and answered (and the answer was even accepted!) almost 2 months ago.   Now you want a new answer "ASAP"?  My consulting fee is $200/hr.